# An Enumerate Approach to a Chronology

Tags: pdftex, lists, longtable, enumerate, tabularray

I have a chronological list to produce with scores of entries. Furthermore, the date for each entry must be positioned a little below the adjoining text.

My previous thought was to use the `longtable` package, which produces entries of the type I am looking for, but without a ``stretch'' to ensure that each page contains entries ranging from the very top to the very bottom of the page.

In any case, my MWE code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\hoffset 10pt \voffset -55pt
\oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8.25in \textwidth 5.75in
\headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\large
\begin{longtable}{m{4.75cm} m{9.5cm}}
\flushright{\vspace{-83pt} {\bf Aug. 25, 1905 ---}} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt] 
\flushright{\vspace*{-64pt} {\bf Aug. 27, 1905 ---}} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt]
\flushright{\vspace{-133pt} \bf Apr. 5, 1912 ---} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt]
\flushright{\vskip -114pt {\bf May 8, 1913 ---}} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt]
\flushright{\vspace{-81pt} {\bf Sept. 30, 1914 ---}} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt] 
\flushright{\vspace*{-64pt} {\bf Jan. 20, 1918 ---}} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt]
\flushright{\vspace{-137pt} \bf Aug. 2, 1925 ---} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\[10pt]
\flushright{\vskip -109pt {\bf Dec. 12, 1928 ---}} & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

Again, the appearance of the entries is essentially what I want, but I have not been able to find an automatic way of stretching them. `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` only seems to apply to a single page.

Moreover, the code is cumbersome as it makes individual vertical adjustments to each entry which is not feasible when there are a lot of entries.

So, I came up with the following "bare-bones" code using `enumerate`, which I can modify later to give me the automatic page stretch I want.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\textbf{Sept. 1, 1910 ---}] A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. %\lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

This appears to be a more feasible solution for I know how to universally stretch multiple entries  across the pages; however, I do not know how to reposition the date so that it appears a little below the top of the adjoining text.

QUESTION: Is using the `enumerate` package as I described an optimal alternative to the cumbersome code I put together using `longtable`? If so, how may I modify the `enumerate` code so that I may reposition the date(s) somewhat below the default position. (Also, if there is a more feasible way to employ the `longtable` approach, or a better approach to both methods---please advise.)

Thank you.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{3}` to see that affects the two pages.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, before posting the question, I had tried different values; 3 might even have been one of them. In light of your comment, I tried your suggestion on the actual document, but unfortunately, it does not accomplish what I am looking for.  Does it matter where, after `\begin{}document` , I place `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{3}`?

Comment: I did with your code. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtAeT.jpg. Try placing it just before `\begin{longtable}{m{4.75cm} m{9.5cm}}`

Comment: @Simon Dispa Yes; thank you. It seems to work nicely for the `longtable` MWE. I'm not sure why it seems not to be doing the same in my actual document. If I may, I would like to ask what exactly the 1.5 and the 3 represent? Thanks again.

Comment: A factor to expand the cells vertically. Default =1.  Perhaps you have an ``\arraystretch` somewhere or a package is changing its value.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Many thanks, I'll have to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enumerate environment is the best suited for automatic stretching.

I propose to use the `enumitem` package, that allow you to define the appearance of the label (and much more):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[lf]{electrum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\large

\SetLabelAlign{crono}{\raisebox{-1ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{#1 ---}}}}

\begin{description}[align=crono, itemindent=0pt, leftmargin=1cm, rightmargin=0cm, parsep=2ex]

\item[Sept. 1, 1910] A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. %\lipsum[2]

\item[September 1, 1910] A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. %\lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the code above, the enumitem command `SetLabelAlign` is used to format the label.

Answer (score 1):

A powerful new package for managing tables is `tabularray`.
Includes a longtable environment.

The main advantage of `tabularray` is that it separates the contents of the table from the style of rows and columns.

That way is very easy and fast to change and try out new styles without touching the cell contents.

See how simple the final code is to fit the width of the columns to the width of the text area, putting the font in bold for the first column and lowering the date a bit.

Note  that the page break is done after a row is completed.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\hoffset 10pt \voffset -55pt
\oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8.25in \textwidth 5.75in
\headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt

%\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[lf]{electrum}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\usepackage{tabularray} % added
\usepackage{adjustbox} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}
    [caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
    ]
{       colspec = {X[-1,r]X[l]}, % auto adjust columns widths   
        width = \linewidth, % width of the table
        abovesep =20pt, % space above the row
        column{1} = {preto=\bfseries\begin{adjustbox}{raise=-1ex}}, % lower cell by 1ex
        column{1} = {appto=\end{adjustbox}},
}   
Aug. 25, 1905 ---   & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\
Aug. 27, 1905 ---   & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\
Apr. 5, 1912 ---    & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\
May 8, 1913 ---     & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\
Sept. 30, 1914 ---  & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\ 
Jan. 20, 1918 ---   & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\
Aug. 2, 1925 ---    & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. \\
Dec. 12, 1928 ---   & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event.  \\
Apr. 24, 1946 ---   & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event.\\
Jan. 11, 1988 ---   & A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event.A description of an event. A description of an event. A description of an event.\\
\end{longtblr}
```